# grep between list of objecst

Tags: linux, bash

I need to generate a file (`grep_file.txt`) starting from a list of objects (`list.txt`) and a file containing some variables for each objects (`info.txt`). The particularity is that in the file list the objects can be repeated and I would like that all are there are maintained, without eliminating the duplicates, and that therefore everyone has in the final file its own information equipped.

With this example I hope to make everything clearer:

```
info.txt: The columns of the file are separeted by "tab"

ABD  cluster1   yes
3d0  cluster2   no
ER5  cluster1   no
T6y  cluster5   yes

list.txt:

ABD
3d0
ER5
T6y
3d0
3d0
ER5
T6y

grep_file.txt:

ABD  cluster1   yes
3d0  cluster2   no
ER5  cluster1   no
T6y  cluster5   yes
3d0  cluster2   no
3d0  cluster2   no
ER5  cluster1   no
T6y  cluster5   yes
```

I tried to use this script:

```
while read p; do
  grep -i "$p" info.txt
done <list.txt > grep_file.txt
```

But the result is this:

```
ABD cluster1    yes
3d0 cluster2    no
ER5 cluster1    yes
T6y cluster5    no
T6y cluster5    no
3d0 cluster2    no
3d0 cluster2    no
ER5 cluster1    yes
T6y cluster5    no
T6y cluster5    no
```

And it isn't correct because the object T6y appears twice more than in the list file.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: In case you are ok with `awk`, you could try like `awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$0;next} ($0 in arr){print arr[$0]}' info.txt list.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is with the use of -i signifying a case insensitive match

ER5 will also match er5 and so

```
T6y cluster5    no
```

as well as:

```
ER5 cluster1    yes
```

To overcome the issue, use grep without -i or if it is needed, be more specific about the search and so use:

```
grep -Ei "^$p" info.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You are raising subprocess "grep" multiple times which is inefficient.
Would you please try:

```
declare -A hash                         # create an associative array
while IFS= read -r line; do             # read the file line by line
    IFS=$'\t' read -r key _ <<< "$line" # split the line on tab
    hash[$key]="$line"                  # store the line with the key
done < "info.txt"

while IFS= read -r key; do              # read the file "list.txt"
    echo "${hash[$key]}"                # print the associated line
done < "list.txt" > "grep_file.txt"
```

Result:

```
ABD     cluster1        yes
3d0     cluster2        no
ER5     cluster1        no
T6y     cluster5        yes
3d0     cluster2        no
3d0     cluster2        no
ER5     cluster1        no
T6y     cluster5        yes
```